# tikzpicture padding

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box, fbox

I don't get where the mysterious white space around this mwe-`tikzpicture` comes from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\img}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0.3333em, inner sep=0]
    \begin{axis}[
    x = 1cm,
    y = 2cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth,thick},
    xmin=-.625,xmax=6,ymin=-.3125,ymax=1.25,
    xtick={-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    extra x ticks={5.5},
    extra y ticks={-0.25},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel=\empty},
    extra y tick style={yticklabel=\empty},
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1,
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$f(t)$,
    minor tick num= 1,
    grid style={thin,densely dotted,black!20}]
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}          
        \begin{figure}
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
            \fbox{\img}
        \end{figure}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Not only is there massive white space on the left and right, but also small white space above and below. In some cases the big space vanishes, but mini gaps between `fbox` and `tikzpicture` always remain.

I need the exact bounding box for an application and therefore this result is somewhat problematic. Of course, if it where for some complicated Bezier-graph, I would manually draw the bounding box, but in this case, this shouldn't be necessary. 
[image: Complete picture]
[image: mini gaps]

Comment: `\newcommand{\img}{`  adds a space - the new line is uncommented. `\end{tikzpicture}
}` adds another - the new line is uncommented. Combining `center` and `figure` will add too much vertical space. Use `\begin{figure}\centering ... \end{figure}` instead.

Comment: Not sure where the tiny gap above the arrow and $f(t)$ comes from.I checked `\rule{1pt}{\ht\strutbox}`, nor does the [outer sep] have any effect.  I suspect you wanted [every node/.style={outer sep=0.333pt), inner sep=0pt}].

Comment: You guys are right, the big space results (of course) from the missing %. Nope, I didn't want [every node/.style={outer sep=0.333pt), inner sep=0pt}] because in this case the t and f(t) are misplaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the horizontal spacing comes from spaces added by `\img` in the form of uncommented new lines. There is a remaining gap top, bottom, left and right of the contents of the `\fbox`.

[image: minimal gap all round caused by ...?]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\img}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0, inner sep=0]
    \begin{axis}[
      outer sep=.3333em,
    x = 1cm,
    y = 2cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth,thick},
    xmin=-.625,xmax=6,ymin=-.3125,ymax=1.25,
    xtick={-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    extra x ticks={5.5},
    extra y ticks={-0.25},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel=\empty},
    extra y tick style={yticklabel=\empty},
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1,
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$f(t)$,
    minor tick num= 1,
    grid style={thin,densely dotted,black!20}]
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}        
  \begin{figure}\centering
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{\img}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The remaining gap comes, I suspect from the fact that the axis environment is a node. If we change `\img` as follows

```
\newcommand{\img}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]
    \begin{axis}[
      outer sep=.3333em,
      name=mab,
    x = 1cm,
    y = 2cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth,thick},
    xmin=-.625,xmax=6,ymin=-.3125,ymax=1.25,
    xtick={-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    extra x ticks={5.5},
    extra y ticks={-0.25},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel=\empty},
    extra y tick style={yticklabel=\empty},
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1,
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$f(t)$,
    minor tick num= 1,
    grid style={thin,densely dotted,black!20}]
    \end{axis}  
    \draw [red] (mab.north west) |- (mab.south east) |- cycle;
    \draw [blue] (mab.outer north west) |- (mab.outer south east) |- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

then we can see that it is the 'outer border anchors' which lie on the boundary of the box.

[image: lines around standard and outer border anchors]

As this shows `\fbox` *is* drawing around the image bounding box, but that box is not the same as the box given by the `north west` and `south east` anchors of the `axis` node. It is, rather, one given by the `outer north east` and `outer south west` border anchors.

Comment: Thanks so far, but in fact I had this big space issue only this one time (as I was to dumb to find the missing %). More relevant to me is this small-gap-issue.

Comment: @UltimateTrick There is no small gap issue. To see this, add `line cap=rect` to the options of the `tikzpicture`. Ti*k*Z dials a bounding box that includes most generous choices of the line caps and joins, everything else would be next-to-impossible to code.

Comment: @UltimateTrick See explanation above. I'm not sure how mine works with Schrödinger's cat's.

Comment: If I add `line cap=rect` to the options of the `tikzpicture`, i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt,line cap=rect]`, the small gaps at the lower left corner are gone, as expected.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm not sure that's the explanation in this case. `axis` is a node, so the picture is basically a node. But `\node [fill=red] {A};` gets no gap. I think the reason is that `axis` is a node with outer border anchors, which most nodes aren't. However, that may be related to the point you made - I don't know enough to figure it out.

Comment: I meant `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]
 \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}`. (Need to run now...)

Comment: Is there a way to disable these outer border anchors so that the "proper" fbox can be calculated?

Comment: @UltimateTrick They are part of the definition of the node which is the `axis` environment. You can override the bounding box, so you could specify that using the inner anchors, I think, but you'd have to do it on a case-by-case basis, since those won't, presumably, always give you the correct bounding box. Or you can just compensate for them with a negative dimension for the `fbox` separation, I guess.

Comment: @UltimateTrick And note that you need to allow for line widths if you're actually using `\fbox`, too, i.e. you'd need half the line width for a gap to not draw over part of the picture.